# How do I create a variable length dropdown list on a ViewModel without repeating code in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, viewmodel, dropdownlistfor

I'm a newbie developer and I need to populate a dropdown list with dates so they can be selected by a website visitor to retrieve certain data.

The list is unusual because it must populate backward from last month up until a year ago. Thus, last month will be the first entry in the list and each previous month will follow. For example, if today is July 5, 2017, the dropdown list will look like this:

```
Jun 2017
May 2017
Apr 2017
Mar 2017
Feb 2017
Jan 2017
Dec 2016
and so on . . .
```

Each month the list gets longer, so I can’t code a fixed length to the list. I came up with the following code, but it won’t build:

```
[RequireLogin]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    bool firstItem = true;
    int x = -1;
    int y = 1;
    int daysFromStartDate = beginDate.Date.Subtract(currentDate).Days;
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

    while (daysFromStartDate >= 30)
    {
        DateTime previousMonth = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(x);
        string pMonth = previousMonth.ToString("MMM");
        string pYear = previousMonth.ToString("YYYY");
        Int32.TryParse(pMonth, out thisMonth);
        Int32.TryParse(pYear, out thisYear);
        if (firstItem)
            firstItem = false;
            SelectListItem item[y] = new SelectListItem() { Text = pMonth + " " + pYear, Value = pMonth, Selected = true };  //<- #1
        else
            SelectListItem item[y]= new SelectListItem() { Text = pMonth + " " + pYear, Value = pMonth, Selected = false };  //<- #2
        items.Add(item[y]);                                                                                                  //<- #3
        x = x--;
        y = y++;
    }
    ViewBag.MonthList = items;
    return View();
}
```

I’m getting several build errors on the “item” variable and I don’t know how to fix them:

1 - Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type. Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression)

2 – A local variable named ‘item’ is already defined in this scope (I know I need to get rid of the dup, but that's just a symptom of my overall logic problem).

3 – Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of the type SelectListItem

Apparently, c# doesn't like me trying to use an index on my list items, as in "item[y]". I thought I was being clever, but this approach totally bombs.

I scoured this site as well as the Internet and read all of the examples I found, but couldn’t find a solution that matched my needs. Can anyone offer some guidance on how to fix this logic?

I believe I've thoroughly explained the problem, but if I'm lacking in precision or clarity, please accept my apology in advance. I'll be happy to respond to requests for more information.

```
                      *******QUESTION EDIT***********
```

This was a sticky one (for me anyway). However, Vlad Stryapko put me on the right track, and with a few tweeks, I got his solution (which I accepted) working. There's still another issue, but unrelated to my original post, so I'll post a separate question for that. Here's my final code:

**My ViewModel**

```
        public SelectList MonthList { get; set; }


        public SelectList ReverseMonthsLists()
        {
            var stringViewOfDates = GetDates().Select(_ => _.ToString("MMM yyyy")).ToList();

            var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = stringViewOfDates[0], Value = stringViewOfDates[0] });

            for (int i = 1; i < stringViewOfDates.Count(); i++)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = stringViewOfDates[i], Value = stringViewOfDates[i] });
            }
            var selectList = new SelectList(list);
            return selectList;
        }


        public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates()
        {
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2017, 6, 1).Date;
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

            int numberOfMonthsToShow = (currentDate.Year - startDate.Year) * 12 + currentDate.Month - startDate.Month;
            if (numberOfMonthsToShow == 0)
                numberOfMonthsToShow = 1;

            var dates = new List<DateTime>(numberOfMonthsToShow);
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMonthsToShow; i++)
            {
                dates.Add(currentDate);
                currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(-1);
            }
            return dates;
        }
```

**My Html View**

```
        @Html.DropDownList("selectList", Model.ReverseMonthsLists(), "Month Selector")
```

The code compiles now, but all I get is "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem" in my dropdown list. I'll pose that as a question in another thread, because I don't believe I'm allowed to ask a second question here.

Comment: What is `thisMonth`, `thisYear`, `beginDate` and `currentDate`? These variables are not passed to the method

Comment: Your question seems to imply the list should always be 12 months? "last month up until a year ago" is 12 months, so why do you say the list gets longer?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Each month the list gets longer'? In your example you don't go until 2017, you also select 2016 too. Why would it become longer?

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. The list starts at 12 months and gets longer each month after that. Every 30 - 31 days the previous months collection of data is accumulated and a new list entry is made to reference that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't quite got what you need to so, here's an example of how you can build a list of dates starting from the current one and containing 12 months.

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates()
{
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    var numberOfMonthsToShow = 12;
    var dates = new List<DateTime>(numberOfMonthsToShow);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMonthsToShow; i++)
    {
        dates.Add(currentDate);
        currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(-1);
    }
    return dates;
}
```

If you want to start from the previous month, initialise currentDate as DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)

Next, you will have to build a string representation of those dates. For your format, use Y format selector.

```
 var stringViewOfDates = GetDates().Select(_ => _.ToString("MMM yyyy"));
```

Now that you have your strings, you can add them to SelectList. I don't have ASP.NET MVC around right now, but it should be pretty trivial. Something like:

```
var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = stringViewOfDates[0], Value = stringViewOfDates[0]})

for (int i = 1; i < stringView.Count(); i++)
{
  list.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = stringViewOfDates[i], Value = stringViewOfDates[i]);
}

var selectList = new SelectList(list);
```

You have a lot of code which seems redundant for a task of 'give me previous months'. Please try the one I've provided or explain why you need so convoluted code. I might be missing some logic of yours.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Using your example, how do I invoke the function to populate the combo box on my view? What I currently have is <select onchange="myFunc(ReverseMonthsLists)" id="monthDropdown" value="dates"></select> but nothing happens.

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the results? You can do that with dropDownList. 

@Html.DropDownList("monthList", ViewBag.SelectList, "Default label", new { @class = "css-class" })

Comment: Thanks for responding Vlad Stryapko, and forgive me for being such a novice. I added your line of code to my cshtml view and got the following error:

"HtmlHelper<ViewModel> has no applicable method named 'DropDownList' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax."

I'm not sure how to resolve that error. Can you offer any guidance?

Comment: Try to use this 

(SelectList)ViewBag.SelectList

instead of just ViewBag.SelectList

Comment: Now I get the error "[InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'monthList'.]" Should I define "monthList" on my ViewModel (that's where I put my function) to eliminate this error. Again, I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Check if you assign SelecList to ViewBag.monthList in your controller.

Comment: Over the last 30 minutes I've done a lot of reading and I tried ViewBag.monthList = selectList, ViewBag.monthList = list and ViewBag.monthList = new SelectList(list) but I keep getting "ViewBag does not exist in the current context". Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you doing that in your controller?

Comment: I'm doing it on the ViewModel, which is where I've put the functions.

Comment: You have to populate ViewBag from the controller code. In your example, use     ViewBag.MonthList = <method to get Select List>;

Comment: I don't have controller code. All of the code is on the ViewModel. And the only thing on the html view is the @Html.DropDownList("monthList", (SelectList)ViewBag.SelectList, "Default label", new { @class = "css-class" }). I was expressly told by management not to put the functions on a controller for performance reasons. Can I do this on the ViewModel?

Comment: Well, I don't see any reasons not to put the code inside the controller but if you don't want to do that, that's what you can do: 1. Put all the code to get SelectList inside some other class 2. In your Index action, call ViewBag.SelectList = OtherClass.GetSelectList();

Answer (score 1):

given a generic function to get the list of dates :-

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReverseMonthList(string format, DateTime start, int count)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(n => start.AddMonths(-(n + 1)).ToString(format));
    }
```

then

```
var from = new DateTime(2016, 7, 5);
var now = new DateTime(2017, 7, 5);
var monthsSinceStart = ((now.Year - @from.Year) * 12) + now.Month - @from.Month;
var dates = ReverseMonthList("MMM yyyy", now, monthsSinceStart);
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ and go backwards:

```
var ans = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(p => start.AddMonths(-p).ToString("MMM yy")).ToList();
```

Comment: Wrap this in a static method and this should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The list is unusual because it must populate backward from last month up until a year ago.

It's easy to do. First - generate dates. You have the start date (previous month) and a total number of months required (12). Then project each date into `SelectListItem`:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var startOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);

var items = from i in Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
            let date = startOfMonth.AddMonths(-i)
            select new SelectListItem { 
                Text = date.ToString("MMM yyyy"), 
                Value = date.ToString("MMM"), 
                Selected = i == 1
            };

ViewBag.MonthList = items.ToList();
```

Notes:

1. You should calculate dates relative to the start of the current month. Otherwise, you can have a problem with February 29.
2. Use string format to produce the date in the format you want. Do not format parts of the date and concatenate them.
3. Year format string is lowercase `yyyy`
4. `SelectListItem item[y] = ...` is incorrect syntax. It's a mix of assignment and declaration. If you want to assign an item in the list, then you should refer to the item by index `item[y] = ...`. But you should check before if the list contains enough items. Actually what you really need to do here is add an item to the list, which is achieved by `items.Add(...)`.
5. Consider to learn [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) - it allows you to write queries (in a declarative way) to easily filter, project, etc data

Answer (score 0):

this is a console app

```
   var startDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

    var days = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    int totalMonths = 12;

    for (int i = 1; i < totalMonths; i++)
    {
        var tempDay = startDate.AddMonths(-i);
        days.Add(new Tuple<string, string>($"{tempDay.ToString("MMM")} {tempDay.ToString("yyyy")}", tempDay.ToString("MMM")));
    }

    foreach (var d in days)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d.Item1);
    }
```

output
Jun 2017
May 2017
Apr 2017
Mar 2017
Feb 2017
Jan 2017
Dec 2016
Nov 2016
Oct 2016
Sep 2016
Aug 2016

for test purpose I have used **tuple**. Use the listitem class. for the item selection use either a separate loop to or use **if** condition in the generation method.